# cvgtest(..) in R always yields error code

Tags: r, var

I want to use the function cvgtest(...) to check my VaR predictions for independence and conditional and unconditional coverage. Whenever I use this function, I get the error message "Object 'model' was not found", even though I did not use this object.

Can anyone help me with his and know how to fix it?

```
> cvgtest(obj = list(loss = returns_stoxx[2226:3225], VaR = VaRStoxx95t$VaRStoXX95, p = 0.95))
Fehler in cvgtest(obj = list(loss = returns_stoxx[2226:3225], VaR = VaRStoxx95t$VaRStoXX95,  : 
  Objekt 'model' nicht gefunden
```

Comment: Try to pass `model=NULL` to the function, or define `model=NULL` before running the function.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have results, but they look somewhat strange for unconditional and conditional test (e.g. p= 00000000000000). Do you know how to deal with this?